# Plugin only server side

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a plugin that I don't want the client to see. Unfortunately it is allways built both for the server and the client. How can this be prevented?

```
<template>
    <div>
        Test
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import getAll from '~/plugins/api'
    export default {
        asyncData (context, callback) {
            getAll(function(data){
                callback(null,data);
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my .vue file. The fetch of the data is working but i can also See the code from the client side which i don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `context.isServer` property.
It's a boolean to let you know if you're actually renderer from the server-side.

```
<script>
import getAll from '~/plugins/api'
export default {
    asyncData (context, callback) {
        if (context.isServer) {
            getAll(function(data){
                callback(null,data);
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

More details about Nuxt context here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/context

---

**update:** (thanks @Lanayx)

*"Note: Since Nuxt.js 2.4, mode has been introduced as option of plugins to specify plugin type, possible value are: client or server. ssr: false will be adapted to mode: 'client' and deprecated in next major release."*

```
// nuxt.config.js:

export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/both-sides.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/client-only.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/server-only.js', mode: 'server' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with this option the plugin is still passed to the client side

Comment: @Lanayx Do you know a solution which is not passing the code to the client side?

Comment: @PhilippS. Looks like `mode: 'server'` is the right solution as of today (https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#client-side-only)

Comment: @Lanayx Thank you! I have a middleware which should be only available on server side. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `.server` suffix to the file should work for nuxt3, for example if your file is `myPlugin.ts` rename it to `myPlugin.server.ts` - this will only be called on the server.