# How to use nuxtjs plugin only in server side?

Tags: nuxt.js, hexo

I have a plugin which will inject some variables to store. But it's a node modules and call some nodejs special API.

I found a config in official docs

```
ssr: Boolean (default to true) If false, the file will be included only on the client-side.
```

But it use for client side only

Here is my plugins codes

```
var Hexo = require("hexo")

export default ({app, store}) => {
  var hexo = new Hexo(process.cwd() + '/hexo',{})

  hexo.load().then(function(){
  var posts = hexo.locals.get("posts")
  var pages = hexo.locals.get("pages")
  var categories = hexo.locals.get("categories")
  var tags = hexo.locals.get("tags")
  store.$commit("init",[posts,pages,categories,tags])
})
}
```

When I run

```
npm run dev
```

console show

```
These dependencies were not found:

* child_process in ./node_modules/hexo-util/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js
* fs in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js, ./node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js and 19 others
* module in ./node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/index.js
```

I have try install these modules, but in their modules folder, there are only have package.json
there don't have *.js files

same question don't have correct anwser.

[Plugin only server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494579/plugin-only-server-side)

Comment: what it all wiht process.server

Comment: @Aldarund Thank you reply. But How I use this variable? use it in nuxt.config.js or use in my plugin file (hexo.js)?

Comment: @Aldarund This very important to my,could you give me some idea? I am try to debug codes but failed..

Comment: in plugin file. Wrap plugin content into if (process.server) { ... }